# Можно ли получить урлы всех результатов умного фильтра в битриксе?

Tags: php, битрикс

Пришла задача вывести в sitemap.xml результаты фильтра по 2м пересечениям свойств в каталоге продукции, но я начинающий и даже пока не понимаю, как вывести все результаты фильтра

Answer (score 0):

Аналогичен CiblockElementLisr , только с условием свойств фильтра. Результат УРЛ

Однако напомню, что поисковики определяют и удаляют дубли страниц. В вашем случае -дубли страниц урлы по фильтрам